# HTTPBuilder/RESTClient 401 handling

Tags: groovy, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpbuilder

I'm building application using groovy HTTPBuilder and I'm kind of stuck on handling 401. In my app every couple of minutes my authentication cookie gets invalidated (request returns 401) and i have to renew it by requesting some resource (say /token/refresh) and then repeat the original request..
I know I can define response.'401' failure closure but i don't want to specify it in every request over and over again. I want to do it more transparently. 
I checked that there already are some authentication strategies (basic, oauth, digest,...) but none of them is suitable for me and implementing something new seems like a lot of work.
I'd like to define some responseInterceptor where I could check response status, and if it's 401, I'd issue token renew request and then repeat the original request (all would be done in that interceptor)
Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

What about intercepting the `request` method call using metaprogramming and handling status 401 there?

I can't test right now, so i'll try a blind shot:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT

def oldRequest = HTTPBuilder.&request 

HTTPBuilder.metaClass.request = { method1, method2, clos ->
  println "handler"
  def authErrorClos = { 
    response.'401' = {
      // handle
    } 
  }

  authErrorClos.delegate = oldRequest

  authErrorClos()

  oldRequest method1, method2, clos

}
```